# Pyspark dataframe operator "IS NOT IN"

Tags: pyspark

I would like to rewrite this from R to Pyspark, any nice looking suggestions?

```
array <- c(1,2,3)
dataset <- filter(!(column %in% array))
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

In pyspark you can do it like this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
dataframe.filter(dataframe.column.isin(array) == False)
```

Or using the binary NOT operator:

```
dataframe.filter(~dataframe.column.isin(array))
```

Comment: What is the job of the `*` in `*array`?

Comment: *variable is python syntax for expanding an array to dump it's elements into the function parameters one at a time in order.

Comment: Note that `dataframe.column` is case sensitive! Alternatively, you can use the dictionary syntax `dataframe[column]`, which is not :)

Comment: Should you not use `is False` instead of `== False`?

Comment: @rjurney No. What the `==` operator is doing here is calling the overloaded `__eq__` method on the `Column` result returned by `dataframe.column.isin(*array)`. That's overloaded to return another column result to test for equality with the other argument (in this case, `False`). The `is` operator tests for object identity, that is, if the objects are actually the same place in memory. If you use `is` here, it would always fail because the constant `False` doesn't ever live in the same memory location as a `Column`. Additionally, you can't overload `is`.

Comment: @JohnMoeller Thanks, John. I appreciate it.

Comment: List splatting with * does not make any difference here. You can just use `isin(array)` and it works just fine.

Comment: @Joe See Michal's comment above - Spark now supports `list` as argument.

Comment: In my opinion it would have been a better design if `column.not_in()` or `column.is_not_in()` was implemented.

Answer (score 52):

Take the operator *~* which means *contrary* :

```
df_filtered = df.filter(~df["column_name"].isin([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Everyone here, shouldn't this be the accepted answer? Why use this not-so-evident-to-understand `== False` when we have `~` specifically for negation?

Comment: Also, `*` was useless

Answer (score 15):

```
df_result = df[df.column_name.isin([1, 2, 3]) == False]
```

Answer (score 4):

slightly different syntax and a "date" data set:

```
toGetDates={'2017-11-09', '2017-11-11', '2017-11-12'}
df= df.filter(df['DATE'].isin(toGetDates) == False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.subtract()` buddy.

Example:

```
df1 = df.select(col(1),col(2),col(3)) 
df2 = df.subtract(df1)
```

This way, df2 will be defined as everything that is df that is not df1.

Answer (score 2):

`*` is not needed. So:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
dataframe.filter(~dataframe.column.isin(list))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use sql functions `.col` + `.isin()`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

array = [1,2,3]
df = df.filter(~F.col(column_name).isin(array))
```

This might be useful if you are using sql functions and want consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop the array and filter:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
for i in array:
    df = df.filter(df["column"] != i)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this in Big Data applications...it means you need to go through the whole dataset tree times...which is huge if you image you have few terrabytes to process

Comment: No, because Spark internally optimices this filter to make in 1 time this filters.

Comment: then it should be ok ... until new breaking change Spark update or framework switch... and 3 rows instead 1 line + hidden optimisation seems still not good pattern for me...no offense, but I still would recommend to avoid it